# Writing a polynomial as product of its roots

Tags: polynomials, summation

A polynomial
$$p=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$$
with roots $x_i, i=1, \cdots, n$ is given. Is it true to say that for any value of $x$
$$\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$$
Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's almost true. You just need to tack the leading coefficient onto the product:
$$\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i=a_n\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)$$